# Repair Win 10 booting on HP z240? Critical system driver missing or contains errors Wdf01000.sys Error Code: 0xc0000242

Tags: windows-10, boot, bsod

Repair Win 10 booting on HP z240? Error:  xxxxxxxxxxx

(Image and details being updated from phone)

[image: Bsod]

Win 10 on HP z240:

Error Code: **0xc0000242**

(Image and details being updated from phone)

> ## Recovery
>
> Your PC/ Device needs to be repaired.
>
> The OS couldnt be loaded because: **Critical system driver missing or contains errors.**
>
> File: **\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\Wdf01000.sys**
> Error Code: **0xc0000242**
>
> Choose one of the options below to address this proboem.
>
> Press Enter to try again
> Press F8 for Startup Settings
> Press Esc for UEFI Firmware Settings

If I press ENTER to try again, it gives me the same.

- I had to disable Automatic Repair to see the above screen as previously I'd be stuck in loops/ repeats of those
- We've tried each of the typical options several times

  - Automatic Repair
  - Startup Repair
  - Several CHKDSK with /F /R
  - System Restore
  - Safe Mode attempts failed,
  - DISM /CleanupImage /ScanHealth /ScratchDir pops error after 86%..

    - "DISM Error 605 - The specified buffer contains ill formed data."
  - Not sure if/ how SFC worked or not?
  - Trying to avoid a Reset PC from Recovery / Wipe clean existing Programs/ Apps etc.
- Wondering if this specifically has to do with the listed file going kaput and if / how to find and add this specific one in particular?
- Only wish we could've run a REPAIR install but that seems to require Windows boot

Some outcomes:

[image: AR2]

[image: Repair]

Comment: You might want to start with the built in hardware diagnostics, to make sure the drive is okay: https://tech.wayne.edu/kb/help-support/cit-help-desk/676

Comment: My experience with these is drive failure (most of the time) and Windows heavy damage (some of the time). Either way, try to recover what you can (USB Windows Boot and copy to USB drive) and then reinstall Windows or replace drive and reinstall Windows.

Comment: I have never in 20+ years working with computers, received this error, when it was NOT connected to an failure with a storage drive.  System files do not become corrupt on a storage drive, that is functional and within specifications.  I also have never recovered from this particular failure.    The DISM command you are using would not repair a corrupted system file by the way (it's the wrong command).

Comment: I have seen it (1 in 5) OS damage and 4 in 5 drive damage. It does cut both ways.

Comment: @John - In my experience that 1 in 5 chance of it being OS damage turns out to be a drive that is about to fail.

Answer (score 0):

Error code 0xc0000242 means a corrupted BCD.
`Wdf01000.sys` is used for AMD devices, usually CPU. In short, your disk has
undergone what is called a catastrophic error.

Use a boot media, either Linux or Windows booting to the Command Prompt,
and save your data.

You could then attempt an
[Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

If successful and if you manage to boot into Windows, your first priority
should be to check the SMART data of your disk, to evaluate the status
of the disk. If you don't have an application for that, use for example
[Speccy](https://www.ccleaner.com/speccy).
You may ask our help in understanding the numbers.

If the SMART data is spotless, then you might have had data corruption
because of a power surge. Run `chkdsk` to verify the file-system.

If the SMART data shows serious errors, consider getting a new disk.